# Foreach with if/else to check file contents

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that takes a file with computer names and checks to see if there is a folder created for them on a share. The script I created below is broken and returns true for every line in the file. The reason for the foreach is to have the folder name listed in the output. Any suggestions?

```
$computer=Get-Content -path 'C:\comp.csv'

foreach ($comp in $computer) {
$path= Test-path '\\UNC_folder_path\'
if ($path -eq $True) {Write-host "$comp = Success"}
Else {Write-host "$comp = Failure"}
}
```

Comment: You're never using the `$comp` variable.  If the foldername on the UNC share is the name of the computer, you need to update your `Test-Path` command: `-Path "\\UNC\$comp"`.  Note the double-quotes: this allows your variable to expand in the string.  Single-quoted strings will be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you are allways testing the same '\UNC_folder_path\' path.

If you want to see if a folder within that path is created, Clev proposition seems fine.
Assuming your csv file only contains computer names

CSV file:

```
cpu1
cpu2
```

Your script :

```
$computer=Get-Content -path 'C:\comp.csv'

foreach ($comp in $computer) {
$path= Test-path '\\UNC_folder_path\$comp' #or $path= Test-path '\\UNC_folder_path\$_'
if ($path -eq $True) {Write-host "$comp = Success"}
Else {Write-host "$comp = Failure"}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess, but did you forget to check for the specific computer's folder on the UNC path?

```
$path= Test-path '\\UNC_folder_path\'
```

Change to

```
$path= Test-path '\\UNC_folder_path\$comp'
```

Comment: Adding the $comp returns all values as "Failure" now instead of all saying "Success"

Comment: the single quotes doesn't expand the variable. use double quotes instead

Comment: @Canoodlekewder please remember to upvote answers that helped you out :) Glad your problem is solved!